# What's the easiest way to copy the URL of a traditional HTML frame in Safari?

Tags: safari, url, links

As much as I hate HTML frames, a vendor uses a documentation platform that makes heavy use of them. Whenever I search for a documentation page, it displays in a frame, and I would like to be able to copy the URL of that page inside the frame to share with colleagues.

I would have expected to be able to do this by right-clicking on the frame and choosing "Copy Frame URL" or something, but that's not an option. At present I have to find the link *to* the page in question in a list of documentation contents, and copy that.

Comment: Could you provide a URL?

Comment: @user3439894 any page with frames. http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/preview.cfm?template=../frames/css_frames/2_rows_2_columns_a.cfm#

Comment: That page doesn't have frames...

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a little indirect however based on your example, right-click in the frame and select **Open Frame in New Tab**, then select the new Tab and copy the URL from the Address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Generally:
Use either the right-click as you stated or you can use Safari's WebInspector from the Developer menu (needs to be turne don in settings -> advanced first) to view a pages source-code and copy out pretty much anything you like.

In your Case:
The page you provided doesn't use any iframes.